# Question regarding increasing function properties

Tags: calculus

How does one prove that for any increasing function this is true $f(x+y)<f(x)+f(y)$ ? $x<y$ and both $x,y>0$ .

Answer (score 2):

Is $y=x$ an increasing function? Does it satisfy the condition that $f(x+y)<f(x)+f(y)$?

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Consider $f(x)=x^2$. $f(1+2)=9>5=f(1)+f(2)$.